# moving from Sqlite3 to mysql - how to copy all data

Tags: django, django-database

I'm currently using sqlite3 in my django app, but now that I'm moving to production, I thought it would be better to move it to mysql. I have a database file 9around 10 mb in size), and i want to copy all this data in the mysql db I created on prod. [Here](http://macrotoma.blogspot.in/2012/10/solved-move-django-from-sqlite-to-mysql.html) is a possible way to do that (using content types), but this method doesnt copy data for manytomany fields.

Is there a way I can safely copy all my data from sqlite3 to mysql db? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the list of converters to help you migrate from Sqllist3 to mysql:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools